Pass data object dynamically route nextjs

I'm experiencing this error when passing an object in another route. My goals is when the button for edit is clicked, i will be routed to the edit page passing also the data of that row to the edit page. When i try passing just only the id it works: router.push(Create/${id}/edit) In the nextjs documentation it says that if passing object
useuseSearchParams()
but can you help me understand when using this?
"use client";

import {
  useReactTable,
  getCoreRowModel,
  flexRender,
  getPaginationRowModel,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { useMemo } from "react";

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const Table = ({ data, columns, showSelectColumn, onDelete }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dataTable = useMemo(() => data, [data]);

  const table = useReactTable({
    data: dataTable,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
  });

  const totalPages = table.getPageCount();

  const currentPage = table.pageIndex + 1; // pageIndex is zero-based

  const pageNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }

  const handleDelete = (rowId) => {
    console.log(dataTable[rowId].id);
    console.log(dataTable[rowId])
    const idToDelete = dataTable[rowId].id; // Access the actual ID of the item
    onDelete(idToDelete);
  };

  const handleEdit = (rowId) => {
    const id = dataTable[rowId].id;
    router.push({
      pathname: `Create/${id}/edit`,
      query: {id: id, ...dataTable[rowId]}
    })
    // router.push(`Create/${id}/edit`)
  }

  return (
    <div className="p-5">
      <table className="text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 table border-collapse w-full">
        <thead className="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
          
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th
                  key={header.id}
                  className="text-left p-2 border-b border-[#C3C6CF] text-white font-medium text-sm text-nowrap uppercase"
                >
                  {flexRender(
                    header.column.columnDef.header,
                    header.getContext()
                  )}
                </th>
              ))}
              <th
                key={"action-header"}
                className="text-left p-2 border-b border-[#C3C6CF]  text-white text-sm font-semibold uppercase"
                style={{ width: "8px" }}
              >
                Action
              </th>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
            <tr key={row.id}>
            
              {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                <td
                  key={cell.id}
                  className="p-2 border-b border-[#C3C6CF] text-[#1A1C1E] font-normal text-sm text-clip"
                >
                  {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                </td>
              ))}
          
              <td className="p-2 border-b border-[#C3C6CF] ">
                <div className="flex">
                  <button
                    className="mr-2 px-3 py-1 bg-green-500 text-white rounded"
                    // onClick={() => router.push(`Create/${row.original.id}/edit`)}
                    onClick={() => handleEdit(row.id)}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
  
                  <button
                    className="mr-2 px-3 py-1 bg-red-500 text-white rounded"
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(row.id)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
              </td>
         
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>

      {/*  for pagination*/}

      <div className="flex justify-between pt-5">
        <button
          onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
          className="px-3 py-1 mx-1 rounded transition-colors bg-white text-black font-bold"
        >
          Previous
        </button>

        {pageNumbers.map((pageNumber) => (
          <button
            key={pageNumber}
            onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(pageNumber - 1)} // pageIndex is zero-based
            disabled={pageNumber === currentPage}
          >
            {pageNumber}
          </button>
        ))}

        <button
          className="px-3 py-1 mx-1 rounded transition-colors bg-white text-black font-bold"
          onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
          disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
        >
          Next Page
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;


https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter follow this since you are using app router. u need to pass the whole url as a string (so include the query params) in the push

So do i still need to use the useSearchParams()? can you gave me an example? I've read in another stackoverflow post that i cant use query  param anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76664553/path-startswith-is-not-a-function-in-next-js

You can still "use search params", just not "useSearchParams", ironically. The hook is gone in the app router, although it's still available in client only components, but instead the props are passed directly into the page automagically. All you have to do is read the "searchParams" prop that will be part of the "/Create" pages props now that you've sent the searchParams over.

Tried the idea that you commented earlier bro.
I think this idea somehow works. Upon checking the console for console.log(dataTable[rowId], 'row') i'm getting the
correct row: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit', body: 'quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto'} but upon applying it to my created params it routed to the edit page like these: Create/1/edit?id=1&someOtherProperty=%5Bobject+Object%5D is this correct?

Try creating the params yourself, but log them first to make sure they're actually getting the data you want them to have. That would be something like this:
 const handleEdit = (rowId) => {
    const id = dataTable[rowId].id;
    let params = new URLSearchParams()
    params.set("id", id)
    params.set("someOtherProperty", dataTable[rowId].thatOtherProperty)
    const pathname = `/Create/${id}/edit?${params.toString()}` // IMPORTANT: Note the leading slash here.
    console.log(pathname) // Remove this once you're sure you're getting the data that you want.
    router.push(pathname)
  }


I think this idea somehow works. Upon checking the console for console.log(dataTable[rowId], 'row') i'm getting the correct row:
{userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit', body: 'quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto'}
but upon applying it to my created params it routed to the edit page like these:
Create/1/edit?id=1&someOtherProperty=%5Bobject+Object%5D
is this correct?

You're trying to assign an object to the parameter. You need to break everything down into a string or a number, and then of course change that "someOtherProperty" key to whichever property you want it to be. You can apply that params.set method as many times as you need to. There's a similar params.append method that you can use if any of your items are an array as well.
Docs

Oh i get it like these:
const handleEdit = (rowId) => {
const id = dataTable[rowId].id;
let params = new URLSearchParams()
params.set("id", id)
params.set("body", dataTable[rowId].body)
params.set("title", dataTable[rowId].title)
params.set("userID", dataTable[rowId].userId)
console.log(dataTable[rowId], 'row')
const pathname = Create/${id}/edit?${params.toString()} // IMPORTANT: Note the leading slash here.
console.log(pathname) // Remove this once you're sure you're getting the data that you want.
router.push(pathname)
}
